# Bad character in format

Tags: r, teradata

I hope someone can help in this great community. I have run for several weeks a script in r which is producing a txt file as output which is then imported in teradata after a daily drop, create of a table. I have never had any issue so far but today I received the error: "Error executing query for record 1:2621. Bada character in format or data...".
I frantically googled all the googalable content but none of it could answer my problem. In fact I also tried to replace the content of the txt file with an old file which was uploaded just fine, and today it generated this horrendous error in return. It is only a small table of 6 columns with these characteristics:

```
Top_wagered_Games   varchar(111) 
 ,support   DEC(9,6)
 ,confidence   DEC(9,6)
 ,lift   DEC(9,2)
 ,cnt    int
 , "date"  date
```

And generally made of few rows (no more than 15). What went wrong? Why is this happening? Could anyone help? 
Teradata provider version: ODBC 15.10.01.01

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some actual input data? How do you import the file?

Comment: Hi dnoeth: from Teredata SQL assistant running: insert into table_name
values (?,?,?,?,?,?)...it then pops up the window where the file is selected..

Comment: Ok, found the solution and I hope this can help in case anyone encounters the same issue. This morning I restarted my pc and updates took place. This is the only reason why I can think of my import failing knowing that the same scripts ran successfully until yesterday. The write.table command in R needed an additional argument to get rid of the header: col.names=F. That fixed the issue of importing data from teradata...